# Is timer a thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-services, timer

can I consider the timer to be a special type of thread?, what's the difference if they are worker "sub-processes" runing asynchronously?

I'm working on a c# Windows Service, specifically c#'s System.Threading.Timer vs System.Threading.Thread (using Thread.Sleep to elapse it)

Comment: I don't quite understand the question.   Can you please flesh it out?  What specific types are you talking about?

Comment: isn't this language agnostic?

Comment: @Milox - there are several kinds of timer facility on Windows. You'd be better off asking about a specific class or API if you have one in mind.

Comment: ah got it!, I'm specifically talking about c#'s System.Threading.Timer vs System.Threading.Thread (using Thread.Sleep to elapse it). I thought this was a general programming concept...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The timer isn't a thread BUT having a timer fire events asynchronously can be regarded as a form of multi-threading - along with all the traditional multi-threading issues!

Answer (score 0):

More like 'What OS?'.  Sleep intervals and timeouts on system calls are usually provided by a delta-queue of user thread handles/pointers/whatever, ordered by remaining timeout-tick, in the kernel.  In those environments where timer objects are provided that fire events by means of some message-dispatch mechanism, a similar approach is normally used.  It's certainly unnecessary, and very wasteful, to maintain a thread-per-timer when more efficient mechanisms are available.